# How to use Perl to add a new child node in XML in the start of the node value

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to add a child element to a node in XML in the start of the node value using [`XML::LibXML`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) in Perl. My XML is:

```xml
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n=1> para1 information </para>
<para n=2><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i=1>subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

and the output I want is:

```xml
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n=1><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para1 information </para>
<para n=2><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i=1><head value="PARA HEADING"/>Subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

I want to add a child node 'head' as above if it is not present in 'para' or 'subpara'.

I have tried this code:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8.8

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml_doc    = $xml_parser->parse_file( xml_file . xml );
my $root       = $xml_doc->getDocumentElement();
my $xml_xc     = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $root );

my @array_list = ( para, deck );

foreach my $xml_sections ( $xml_xc->findnodes( '//*' ) ) {

    if ( $xml_sections->nodeName ne "head" ) {

        my $marker_flag = 0;

        foreach my $first_child ( $xml_sections->childNodes() ) {

            if ( $first_child->nodeName eq "head" ) {
                $marker_flag = 1;
                last;
            }
        }

        if ( !$marker_flag ) {

            foreach my $array_elt ( @array_list ) {

                if ( $array_elt eq $xml_sections->nodeName ) {
                    my $new_tag = $xml_doc->createElement( "head" );
                    my $value   = "PARA HEADING";
                    my $att1    = $xml_doc->createAttribute( "value", "$value" );
                    $new_tag->setAttributeNode( $att1 );
                    $xml_sections->addChild( $new_tag );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

print $root->toString();

exit 0;
```

My output is:

```xml
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n=1>para1 information <head value="PARA HEADING"/></para>
<para n=2><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i=1>subpara Info<head value="PARA HEADING"/></subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you are not adding a text element to the $new_tag you are adding, and you are not removing the text element for para1 information. So <para> still has text and <head> does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making things very difficult for yourself! For instance, there's no need to involve `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` unless your XML data has non-default namespaces, which your sample doesn't. Also, the 
values of the attributes to the `para` and `subpara` elements like `n=1` should have quotes around them, giving `n="1"` and so on

Here's a solution that uses an XPath expression to find all `para` or `subpara` elements, and uses `exists` to check whether each of them already has a `head` child. The scalar `$head` is set up with the data that you want to insert, and a clone of it is inserted before the first child of each element that was found

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $doc = $parser->parse_fh(*DATA);

my $head = $parser->parse_balanced_chunk('<head value="PARA HEADING"/>');

for my $para ( $doc->findnodes('//para | //subpara') ) {
    if ( not $para->exists('head') ) {
        $para->insertBefore($head->cloneNode(1), $para->firstChild);
    }
}

print $doc;



__DATA__
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n="1"> para1 information </para>
<para n="2"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i="1">subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

#### output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/> para1 information </para>
<para n="2"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `insertBefore` and `addChild` methods of [`XML::LibXML::Node`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

for my $node ( $dom->findnodes("//para | //subpara") ) {
    my $newnode = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => '<head value="PARA HEADING"/>' )->findnodes('//*')->[0];

    my @children = $node->childNodes();

    if ( !@children ) {
        $node->addChild($newnode);
    } elsif ( $children[0]->nodeName ne 'head' ) {
        $node->insertBefore( $newnode, $children[0] );
    }
}

print $dom->toString;

__DATA__
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n="1"> para1 information </para>
<para n="2"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i="1">subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<book>
<title>
Test title for xml
</title>
<para n="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/> para1 information </para>
<para n="2"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
</book>
</root>
```

Comment: Don't need the `if`; the "else" clause works even when `@children` is empty.

Comment: That's true, although the condition would need to be prefixed with `!@children ||`.

Comment: Right, missed that it was an `elsif`. So what I meant is that you could have used `if ( !@children || $children[0]->nodeName ne 'head' ) {
        $node->insertBefore( $newnode, $children[0] );
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, you can run an XSLT tranformation using its `<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:otherwise>` logic. As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is declarative, special-purpose programming language (same type as SQL is but with databases) used specifically to transform, style, re-format, or re-structure XML documents.

**Perl** (*[generic script](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch22_08.htm)*)

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXSLT;

my $xml_parser  = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml_doc     = $xml_parser->parse_file($XML_FILENAME);

my $xslt_parser = XML::LibXSLT->new;    
my $xsl_doc     = $xml_parser->parse_file($XSL_FILENAME);

my $stylesheet  = $xslt_parser->parse_stylesheet($xsl_doc);
my $results     = $stylesheet->transform($xml_doc);
my $output      = $stylesheet->output_string($results);

print $stylesheet->output_string($results);
```

**XSLT** (*save as .xsl file to be used above*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para" name="paratemplate">      
      <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="string-length(head/@value)>0">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:element name="head">
              <xsl:attribute name="value">PARA HEADING</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
          </para>          
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>      
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subpara" name="subparatemplate">      
      <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="string-length(head/@value)>0">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <subpara>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>  
            <xsl:element name="head">            
              <xsl:attribute name="value">PARA HEADING</xsl:attribute>              
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>  
          </subpara>          
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <book>
    <title>
Test title for xml
</title>
    <para n="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/> para1 information </para>
    <para n="2"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>para2 information<subpara i="1"><head value="PARA HEADING"/>subpara Info</subpara><xyz/></para>
  </book>
</root>
```